# How to align 2 buttons in twitter bootstrap in one div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use twitter bootstrap 2 version.

```
<div class="span4">
    <a href="http://test.com" class="btn">&{'main.menu.with.me'}</a>            
    <a href="http://test2.com" class="btn btn-info pull-right">&{'main.menu.raise.request'}</a>
</div>
```

I need to put 2 buttons to the right with space between them. But if I put pull-right to both there is no space between them, I injecting   doesn't help.

Comment: looks side by side to me => http://jsfiddle.net/4qaY3/

Comment: @NoobEditor if you make the page bigger you see that one button sticks to the left while the other stays to the right, what he wants is probably something like: `|button1| |button2|`

Comment: @rmagnum2002 : thats my bad...thanks for putting on same page!! :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

not very good at html, but I'd do something like this:

**bootstrap 2**:

```
<div class="span4">
 <div class='pull-right'>
   <a href="http://test.com" class="btn">&{'main.menu.with.me'}</a>         
   <a href="http://test2.com" class="btn btn-info">&{'main.menu.raise.request'}</a>
 </div>
</div>
```

in this case you'd want a div.clearfix after the one with pull-right and there is no css involved unless you want more space between buttons then bootstrap already has.

(update 4.08.2016) **bootstrap 3**:

```
<div class='btn-toolbar'>
  <a href="http://test.com" class="btn">&{'main.menu.with.me'}</a>         
  <a href="http://test2.com" class="btn btn-info">&{'main.menu.raise.request'}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: bootstrap 3 options with class='btn-toolbar' works perfectly with pull-right on each button.

Comment: I think that adding pull-right to btn-toolbar is better.

Answer (score 4):

simply add `pull-right` to both the buttons

the, to give space :

```
.btn{
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

**Also,** keep in mind that, `pull`ing right would change the order of the buttons...so better swap according to your layout (*i have done that in my fiddle example*)

[**fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4qaY3/2/)

Comment: This works fine, but is it considered a bad practice or confusing to others looking at the code later?

Comment: @bobtheowl2 : nope, its just CSS over writing, generally changing default css of bootstrap is not advised, so writing a custom overwriting css is a better practice! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
.span4 .btn {
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```